# Can I "Add to Reading List" from a link context menu in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, reading-list

I'm using Safari 13.0.1 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. I can add the current web site to the reading list by pushing the sharing button and then selecting *Add to Reading List*.

Now I want to that **without** opening the page first. So the context menu of a link in Safari has a *Share* menu entry, but there's no *Add to Reading List* in its options. In *System Preferences* - *Extensions* - *Share Menu*, *Add to Reading List* **is** enabled. But it still doesn't show in a link's *Share* context menu. I disabled and enabled *Add to Reading List* to no avail —  other entries in there immediately hid and reappeared in a link's *Share* context menu when unchecking/checking them here.

So, can I get *Add to Reading List* into a link's *Share* context menu in Safari? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't there in the context menu?

[image]

Also some links are javascript instead of URL. Such a link might not be added to the reading list.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right, it was staring me right into the face. It helps if you can read...